# Groovy-Ant Preserve File Structure in Zip Archive

Tags: ant, groovy, antbuilder

I am working with Ant in Groovy, and I want to operate on all files in a directory that match certain criteria. I have the following:

```
def fileSet = ant.fileset(dir: srcDir, id: "files", includes: pattern){
    date(datetime: time when: "before", pattern: datePattern)
}

ant.zip(destfile: "$destDir/$newZipFileName"){
            fileset(refid: "files")
        }
```

This works great on the files in the source directory. But how can I get it to also archive the directories in the source location, while maintaining the directory structure in the archive?

"**/*" as my pattern got all the files, but flattened them into one directory

I've tried using a dirset instead of a fileset, but to no avail.

How can I zip everything up while mirroring the existing directory structure in the archive?
(To clarify, I define the fileset outside of my task because I have several tasks that might use the same fileset, and it gets passed around).

Comment: Is the issue empty directories? (These would be missing from an ANT fileset)

Comment: Another option to check is to use the "basedir" option for the zip task. In other words forget the fileset and tell and to zip up and entire directory.